# Javascript new object (function ) vs inline invocation

Tags: javascript, function, private, members

Is there any considerations to determine which is better practice for creating an object with private members?

```
var object = new function () { 
   var private = "private variable";
   return {
       method : function () { 
           ..dosomething with private;
       }
   }
}
```

VS

```
var object = function () {
 ...
}();
```

Basically what is the difference between using NEW here, and just invoking the function immediately after we define it?

Comment: [Never ever use `new function(){…}`!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10406585/1048572) Admittedly, in this particular case where you `return` from the function it's not *that* bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `new` operator causes the function to be invoked like a [Constructor Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function).

I've seen that pattern before, but I don't see any benefits of using it.

The purpose of the `new` operator is to create an object (the `this` value inside the constructor), setting the right `[[Prototype]]` internal property, to build the *prototype chain* and implement inheritance (you can see the details in the [`[[Construct]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2.2) operation).

I would recommend you to stay with the *inline invocation* pattern.

Comment: While I agree with CMS because you are using a revealing module pattern and relying on lexical scoping - I would clarify that `new` is appropriate when creating a class-like object built upon a prototype pattern - for example a BackboneJS Model or View.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using functions as event handlers you can get memory leaks. Have a look at some of the [articles](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/)

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://jsperf.com/new-function-vs-immediate-function) provides statistics which also confirms that inline invocation pattern is better.

Please note that the measurement is in `operations per second` which the higher the better