# Is it right to think of a Javascript Function Expression that uses the 'new' keyword as 'static'

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to understand Javascript a little deeper.

I created a 'class' `gameData` that I only want ONE of, doesn't need a constructor, or instantiated.

So I created it like so...

```
var gameData = new function () {

    //May need this later 
    this.init = function () { 
    };

    this.storageAvailable = function () {
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Realizing that the 'new' keyword doesn't allow it to be instantiated and makes it available LIKE a static class would be in C#.

Am I thinking of this correctly?  As static?

Comment: If you only need a single instance of an object, why use a constructor at all?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  I created it this way as opposed to a basic object literal so I could have private and public properties and methods.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008086/no-ways-to-have-class-based-objects-in-javascript/17008693#17008693

Comment: see also [`new function()` with lower case “f” in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2274695/1048572)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, it is not static because it still has a `constructor` property pointing to your "anonymous" function. In your example, you could use

```
var gameData2 = new (gameData.constructor)();
```

to reinstantiate a second object, so the "class" (instance actually) is not really "static". You are basically *leaking* the constructor, and possibly the data that is bound to it. Also, a *useless* prototype object (`gameData.constructor.prototype`) does get created and is inserted in the prototype chain of `gameData`, which is not what you want.

Instead, you might use

- a single, simple object literal (as in [Daff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406569/1048572)). That means you don't have a constructor, no closure-scoped private variables (you have used none anyway) and no (custom) prototype.
- the (revealing) module pattern (as in [jAndy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406568/1048572)). There you'd have an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/1048572) to create closure-scoped variables, and can return any kind of object.
- an actual constructor ("class") that can be instantiated later (when needed), and yields the same singleton object always.

This is what the singleton pattern would look like:

```
function GameData() {
    if (this.constructor.singleton)
        return this.constructor.singleton;
    else
        this.constructor.singleton = this;

    // init:
    // * private vars
    // * public properties
    // ...
}
GameData.prototype.storageAvailable = function () {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};

var gameData = new GameData();
var gameData2 = new GameData();
gameData === gameData2 === GameData.singleton; // true
```

Yet, the prototype is quite useless because you have only one instance of `GameData`. It would only get interesting with inheritance.

Answer (score 16):

There is no *Class* in ECMAscript, there is only *Object*.

When `new` is used to invoke a function, we call it a *constructor function*. This function somewhat auto returns a new object once it finished. Any data that is stored within that object using `this` (which references that newly created object) is returned as property of that object. Beside that, `new` sets a property called *constructor* to exactly this function.

In your case, you don't even really require the usage of `new`, you could easily re-write your   code as follows:

```
var gameData = (function () {
    var public = { },
        private = { }; // any private data can get stored here

    //May need this later 
    public.init = function () { 
    };

    public.storageAvailable = function () {
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    return public;
}());
```

This is called the *factory pattern*, *singleton pattern*, *module pattern*, and there might be some other names.

Comment: you should call it a "self-invoked anonymous factory".

Comment: Thanks!  This looks very interesting.. and something MORE for me to try and digest! :)

Comment: @toddv: a very good advice and recommendation is "JavaScript: The good parts" by Douglas Crockford to get into ECMAscript inheritance, Objects+prototypes.

Comment: I think singleton is a quite different pattern, because singletons are still instances of a "class".

Comment: This is not the singleton pattern. Also, ES -> ES5.

Comment: `There is no Class in ECMAscript`. Actually, with ES6, now there is.

Comment: Isn't that just a cleaner syntax for the same thing? - "Classes are in fact functions"  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is just a simple JavaScript object:

```
var gameData = {
    //May need this later 
    init : function () { 
    },

    storageAvailable : function () {
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use private variables create a revealing module pattern style wrapper. This is basically what jAndy suggested:

```
var gameData = (function() {
    var private = 'private variable';

    return {
        //May need this later 
        init : function () { 
        },

        storageAvailable : function () {
            if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: I didn't go this route because I wanted to have public and private methods and constructors...and that cannot be accomplished using object literals...correct?

Comment: I updated my answer for private variables. I don't see why you would need a constructor for a static class though?