# JavaScript difference between function and new function

Tags: javascript, new-operator

The following JavaScript code is very confusing to me. Could anyone help me understand. Why does PersonY not have prototype property.

```
PersonX = function(){};
PersonY = new function(){};
alert(PersonX.prototype);
alert(PersonY.prototype);    
​
```

Comment: Use `function`, not `new function`.

Comment: Just do [never ever use the second construct](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
PersonX = function(){};
```

Places a reference to an anonymous function into `PersonX`. `PersonX` points to a function.

```
PersonY = new function(){};
```

Places a reference to a newly constructed instance of an anonymous constructor function into `PersonY`. `PersonY` points to an object.

---

Regarding the prototype, `PersonY` has one. However, since there were no properties and methods attached to the constructor [before](http://jsfiddle.net/tcrKW/1/) nor [after](http://jsfiddle.net/tcrKW/) instantiation, it has a *blank prototype**.

You can actually check `PersonY`'s prototype by doing `console.log(PersonY)`. You will see that it has a prototype property (I see it as `__proto__` in Chrome) which is "blank". But it has 2 hidden properties, `constructor` which is the constructor function that made the object, and another `__proto__` which leads you to the next "chain link" which would be the `Object` object.

<sub>*Not really blank since prototype is a chain. This prototype level may be blank, but the next higher prototype may have, or in this case, does have properties and methods.</sub>

```
Object prototype -> Constructor prototype -> Your Instance will have:
- toString()        - blank                  - toString()
- hasOwnProperty()                           - hasOwnProperty()
- and more...                                - and more...
                                             - ...but nothing from Constructor
```

Comment: Yes. `typeof new function(){} => "object"`

Comment: @rkmax You can't compare them. Both do different things.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is actually a object instantiated in memory as a copy of the function; the prototype really only has meaning in the context of a creation of the instance, so once it is created, there is no logical construct for what that means.