# jquery Firefox doesn't fire window.onload

Tags: jquery

the following code works fine on chrome but in fire fox. it only works once and then if I refresh the page it won't work again.
any idea on how to fix that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = new function() {
      $(document).on('click', 'div', function() {
            if ($(".ystq_buddy").hasClass("ystq_swipe-right") || $( 
                  ".ystq_buddy" ).hasClass( "ystq_swipe-left")) {

                   $(document.forms['f1']).submit();
            }
      }); 
};
</script>
```

Comment: why are you using window.onload when you have jquery?

Comment: Remove the `new`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript difference between function and new function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557213/javascript-difference-between-function-and-new-function)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs  when I use   $(document).ready(function() {  it doesn't work at all

Comment: @DirWolf odd - every case of js, I use document.ready and it 100% works - how are you including your scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works now fine when I used

```
$( window ).load(function() {
```

thanks all for efforts.