# Function object and Function are they same?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is

```
var myFunc = function() {

}
```

similar to `myFunc = new function () { }`

I read in the documentation it says both mean the same. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score -1):

They are not the same.

- `var myFunc = function(){}` `myFunc` is a reference to anonymous [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).
- `var myFunc = new function (){}` reference to newly constructed **instance** of anonymous function expression.

```js
var myFunc = function() {}

var myFunc1 = new function() {}

// it is the same as doing:
var myFunc2 = new myFunc;


console.log(myFunc, ' and the type is ', typeof myFunc)
console.log(myFunc1, ' and the type is ', typeof myFunc1)
console.log(myFunc2, ' and the type is ', typeof myFunc2)
```

You can reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557213/javascript-difference-between-function-and-new-function) as well