# "new" operator before declaring function

Tags: javascript

Like explore javascript as my first reference to the whole programming but as i'm not the professional  can't comprehend a lot of stuff.
So it would be so much appreciated if someone can explain what actually happens behind the scene.

In body tag  i declared two functions one with "new" and another one without.

- new function sayHi () {alert('hi')}
- function sayHello () {alert('hello')}

So the first function is invoked without usage of (), so i can see "hi" just while document is loading as i understand it correctly. But to see "hello" i should use something like sayHello.call() somewhere in the code.

I guess i understand main purpose of the "new" operator as a creating object instances, furthermore even can assume that there is a slight difference between declare instances of the function object with or without 'new' operator.

But what actually happens  so that the document executes the function with 'new' operator while it's definition, and another one just leaves somewhere in the memory?

Answer (score 3):

1) you don't use `new` when defining the function, but rather you use `new` when you call the function with the intent to make a new object.

2) if you use `new` when you're defining the function, it means that it will fire right away. This can be handy sometimes...  ...but it's really not how a beginner should learn.  Also, the more-accepted version of this technique is called an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), which looks like

```
(function () {
/* function stuff in here */
}());
```

instead of

```
new function () { /* function stuff in here */ }
```

If you try to define a function that way, you will get an error if you try to use it, later (because it's not defined).

Here are two ways of actually defining functions:

```
var sayHi = function () { console.log("Hi!"); };
```

and

```
function sayHello () { console.log("Hello"); }
```

Neither of these use `new`.

In order to call them, and have them do their job, you don't need to use `.call()`.
`.call()` will work, but it has a special purpose which you won't need for a very long time.

All you need to do is this:

```
sayHello();
sayHi();
```

New is intended to be used when you want to make a certain kind of object.

Making objects in JavaScript is very simple:

```
var obj = {};
var person = { name : "Bob" };

person.name; // "Bob"
person.age = 32;
```

Working with objects is very, very easy.

But in other programming languages, you need `classes` which are like blueprints for an object.

In JS, you might make a class like this:

```
function Person (name, age) { this.name = name; this.age = age; }
```

and then use it like:

```
var bob = new Person("Bob", 32);
bob.name; // "Bob";
bob.age;  // 32;
```

See where I put the `new`?
I used a function which makes people, and I said that I want `bob` to be a `new Person`.

But again, in JS, this can be as easy as:

```
var mike = { name : "Mike", age : 20 };
```

Didn't have to build a function, didn't have to use `new`. It just worked.

Comment: Actually, [using `new` + function expression](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572) is never handy.

Comment: I'd agree, but the typical IIFE uses apply. And aside from a few side-effect differences (each providing different side-effects), they achieve the same functionality, which is why I mentioned that what's actually happening is an IIFE, which is typically accomplished using `(function () { /* implementation */ }());` But I totally get what you're saying and agree.

Comment: Just after the year i managed to appreciate your time spent on the extended and full answer. Thank you )))

Answer (score 1):

Those are completely different things. The second one is a standard javascript function *declaration* (and can be called with `sayHi();`), while the first should be rewritten as

```
new (function sayHi() { alert('hi'); });
```

Now you can see it is a [(named) function *expression*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname), which is directly passed to the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). This [should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572), if you really wanted to call it immediately ([there are applications](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)) use `(function(){…})());`.

Comment: You don't need to surround the first example in parentheses.

Comment: @w3d: No, you don't need to, but I did to highlight how it is parsed.