# "new" Before Anonymous Function Invocation Returning Object

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the KnockoutJS source code.

I ran into the following line which I'm not sure I understand...

```
ko.utils = new (function () {
```

Generally, the structure seems to be along the lines of:

```
ko.utils = new (function () {

   // some variables declared with var

   return {
        export:value,
        export:value
   };

})();
```

I don't understand this construct, why is `new` needed? What does it do? What is it useful for?

(I thought that if a function is called with `new` before its name it is invoked as a constructor, and if it returns an object it's identical to an invokation without `new`.)

**UPDATE:** I asked the KnockoutJS team on github and this is what I got back:

> My guess is that Steve just didn't know that it wasn't needed. Looking back at his original commit, I see a lot of unnecessary news that have since been removed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `new` has no effect in this case

Comment: Related: [Is it right to think of a Javascript Function Expression that uses the 'new' keyword as 'static'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406552/is-it-right-to-think-of-a-javascript-function-expression-that-uses-the-new-key)

Comment: Just happened to come across both of them…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be some pattern which prevents `this` to reach the global context (not in this case, since every variable is declared `var`, but the author might wanted to use it as a general pattern to create objects).

```
var x = new (function () {
   this.foo = "bar";
   return {
        // whatever
   };
})();

console.log(foo); // Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined 

var x = (function () { // without new
   this.foo = "bar";
   return {
        // whatever
   };
})();

console.log(foo); // "bar"
```

Comment: +1 That's very clever :) (of you to figure out that reasoning). The sort of thing `"use strict";` avoids. That's completely satisfactory, thanks.