# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, coffeescript

```
$ ->
   window.app.helpers = new class Helpers

    constructor: (@name) ->
      @slideRecipeId     = $("#slideRecipe")
      @specialities      = ["A", "B", "C"]

      setTimeout @countUpRecipes, 3000

    countUpRecipes: ->
      @slideRecipeId.html(@specialities[Math.floor(Math.random() * @specialities.length)])
```

The problem is that on load I get these errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

What's wrong with the code ? Thanks.

Comment: if you `console.log @specialities` in the `countUpRecipes` function, what do you get?

Comment: `countUpRecipes: =>` see http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow

Comment: Check your indentation on the functions here on stackoverflow they look to be indented 1 space while everything else is 2 spaces.

Comment: asawyer is correct, use a fat arrow in the definition of countUpRecipes. @asawyer you should post that as an answer, possibly with a little bit of explanation.

Comment: [Avoid that `new class {…}` pattern!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406552/is-it-right-to-think-of-a-javascript-function-expression-that-uses-the-new-key) Is that supposed to be a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the context when calling `@countUpRecipes`:

```
setTimeout => 
    @countUpRecipes
, 3000
```