# Object creation in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code:

```
var items = [0,1];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var obj = new function() { 
    this.item = items[i];
  }
  window.setTimeout(function() { console.log(obj.item); }, 1000);
}
```

And the result is:

```
1
1
```

But I would have expected this:

```
0
1
```

I am a little bit puzzled. What is the best way to obtain this result?

I think this question is actually different than [Javascript closure inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
because I can already do this:

```
var items = [0,1];
var objs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var obj = new function() { 
    this.item = items[i];
  }
  objs.push(obj);
  window.setTimeout(function() { console.log(obj.item); }, 1000);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  console.log(objs[i].item);
```

And the result of the second loop will be:

```
0
1
```

The problem is to call the right obj from the setTimeout.

Comment: Welcome to the JS closures! :)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: You are reassigning objet's item in each loop

Comment: you should use `for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)` instead using 2

Comment: No, the problem is the same as in that duplicate. Read the answers and understand the implications. And [avoid that `new function(){}` pattern!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406552/is-it-right-to-think-of-a-javascript-function-expression-that-uses-the-new-key)