# Difference between two JS examples?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I've written a JS object that obfuscates email addresses, however I've discovered two slightly different ways of doing so (each with 1 private method and 1 public method):

Object 1:

```
var email = new function()
{
    function encrypt(code, key)
    {
        <eliminated for brevity>
    };

    this.mailto = function(address, name)
    {
        link = encrypt(<code>, <key>);
        document.write('<a href="mailto:'+ link +'">'+ name +'</a>');
    }
};
```

Object 2:

```
var email = function()
{
    function encrypt(code, key)
    {
        <eliminated for brevity>
    };

    return {
        mailto: function(address, name)
        {
            link = encrypt(<code>, <key>);
            document.write('<a href="mailto:'+ link +'">'+ name +'</a>');
        }
    };
}();
```

Both of these syntaxes work and can be called with:

```
email.mailto('example', 'Example');
```

I'm particularly interested in memory usage or extensibility.
It looks to me as if Object 1 would create a new instance every time it's called?

What are the differences?

Comment: They both terrible for leaking global variables and using document.write... And there is no *practical* difference (there could be, if `this` was used in any of them).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it right to think of a Javascript Function Expression that uses the 'new' keyword as 'static'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406552/is-it-right-to-think-of-a-javascript-function-expression-that-uses-the-new-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks to me as if Object 1 would create a new instance every time it's called?

No. You're doing this with the `new` keyword already (and once only), `email` is a static object.

> What are the differences?

The first `email` object does inherit from an extra prototype object that is not apparent in the code. Yet, it does e.g. store the initialisation function, making it non-anonymous. You could create another instance of your module by

```
var email2 = new (email.constructor)();
```

This is completely superfluous and probably unintentional.

> I'm particularly interested in memory usage

The first option does have an additional prototype object and needs to hold the constructor function in memory, while the second one can garbage-collect the [IEFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) after it was used. Use the second pattern only, **avoid the first one**.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. But what's IIFE?

Comment: Immediately-invoked function expression, the construct used for the revealing module pattern (just what you have in example #2)

Comment: Last question: In the second example, do all public methods go in the return statement (I've seen this before but don't understand it)?

Comment: Yes. The object [literal] that you are returning is the one that is assigned to the `email` variable.