# Javascript Object or new function for function handler

Tags: javascript

I am a bit confused as which one of the following is the right way to create a handler containing functions...An object with function or a new function itself?
Say, a handler for calculator functions...

```
CalculatorHandler = new function(){
    this.add = new function(a, b){
          return a + b;
    };
    this.sub = new function(a, b){
          return a-b;
    };
};
```

Or

```
CalculatorHandler = {
    this.add: function(a, b){
          return a + b;
    },
    this.sub: function(a, b){
          return a-b;
    }
};
```

Are there any advantage/disadvantage of one over the other?

Comment: the second is not valid syntax

Comment: …and the first pattern [should not be used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10406585/1048572)

Comment: @chumkiu I also thought that at first, but now I think that it is valid (though it won't work properly here).  All that the `new` keyword wants is a function to invoke, and it's got that here. The resulting value of course will be a plain object and not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to have a "basket" to hold your functions together, simply use an object, there is no need for a constructor function:

```
CalculatorHandler = {
    add: function(a, b){
          return a + b;
    },
    sub: function(a, b){
          return a-b;
    }
};
```

Note how the `this` in your example is incorrect as it will refer to the scope you define the CalculatorHandler object in (probably global - window).

On the other hand if you want to build a calculator to have some data and do operations on it, then you can use the OOP-like approach in your first example.

```
CalculatorHandler = function() {
  this.total=0;

  this.add = function(a) {
    this.total += a;
  };

  this.sub = function(a) {
    this.total -= a;
  };
}

var calc = new CalculatorHandler();
calc.add(4);
calc.sub(3);
```

And a better solution, based on prototipal inheritance:

```
CalculatorHandler = function() {
  this.total=0;
}

CalculatorHandler.prototype.add = function(num) {
  this.total += num;
}

CalculatorHandler.prototype.sub = function(num) {
  this.total -= num;
};

var calc = new CalculatorHandler();
calc.add(4);
calc.sub(3);
```