# Initializing nested Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods

I have a Javascript object nested within another object like so:

```
function Outer() {
    this.outerProp;
    this.inner = new function() {
        this.innerProp;
    }
}
```

I need to create a method to initialize the inner object. I could nest the init method inside the inner object, or I could place it outside the scope of the inner object:

```
var outer = new Outer();
outer.inner.init();  // Option 1
outer.initInner();  //Option 2
```

Would one of these options be preferred over the other? I'm leaning toward Option 1 so that I can bundle all of the data and methods related to outer.inner together. Is there any reason not to do it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm leaning toward Option 1 so that I can bundle all of the data and methods related to outer.inner together.

Yes. Encapsulation is exactly the reason to do it this way, instead of having some unrelated method on `outer`. You even might want to take the `inner` constructor out of the `outer` part and only call it from there.

> ```
> … = new function() { … }
> ```

[Do not use this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406585/1048572). Use an object literal or a plain [IEFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) instead.