# Javascript module pattern and module functions

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

```
var pagger = new function () {

var _a = 1;
var _b = 2;

function add() {
    return _a + _b;
}
return {
    A: _a,
    B: _b,
    Add: add

        };
};

//return 1
alert(pagger.A);
pagger.A=2; 
pagger.B=2;

//return 2
alert(pagger.A);


//return 3
alert(pagger.Add());
```

If I use this way to create object A and B are accessor for private _a and _b but if I try to change property _a trough A,  function Add not take that in account. Is there way to make this work?

Comment: btw, console.log is usually a much better way to print values for debugging than alert.

Comment: [Do not use `new function()`!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10406585/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use getters and setters:

```
return {
    getA: function(){ return _a },
    setA: function(x){ _a = x },
    //...
}
```

---

Actually, the `.A` field is not an acessor to a private variable like in other OO languages. Its just a hashtable field that initially points to what `_a` was currently stored. If you mutate `_a` or `.A` afterwards, one will not interfere with the other.

---

A simpler alternative would be to make those fields public isntead of wrapping some inner variables:

```
function make_pager(){
   return {
       A : 1,
       B : 2,
       Add: function(){
           //use the dynamically scoped "this" instead 
           //of lexical variables
           return this.A + this.B
       }
   }
}

var pager = make_pager();

pager.A = 10;
console.log(pager.Add());
```

Comment: is this the only way I checked and works great but apparently prop A should be explicitly defined with getter and setter?

Comment: @plamtod: If you want private variables then getters and setters are the only way. However, you could always make those fields public and store the info in a single place (see my edit).