# "Not a constructor", but the types check out

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor

Yes, this has been asked to death before, but [none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107198/javascript-not-a-constructor-exception-while-creating-objects) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008793/javascript-typeerror-is-not-a-constructor) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385366/typeerror-not-a-constructor) work for me.

I'm getting a `TypeError: Config is not a constructor` when calling the `Config` constructor. Going through other SO questions and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor), it appears the usual cause of this error is either shadowing the constructor or calling a non-callable type, but neither of these check out in my project.

This is the call:

```
var Server = require("./server.js").Server;
var Config = require("./config.js").Config;

new Server(new Config("app/config.json")).run();
```

In `./config.js`:

```
var fs = require("fs");

exports.Config = file => {
  var json;

  if (fs.existsSync(file) && !fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()) {
    json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file));
  }
  else {
    throw new ReferenceError("File doesn't exist: can't load config");
  }

  this.has = key => {
    return json.hasOwnProperty(key);
  };

  this.get = key => {
    return json[key] || null;
  };

  this.set = (key, value, write) => {
    json[key] = value;
    if (write) {
      fs.writeFileSync(file, JSON.stringify(json));
    }
  };
};
```

Logging the type of `Config` before calling it reveals that it's a `Function`, so it's almost certainly the same function as is defined in `config.js`. So, why is Node telling me it's not a constructor?

Comment: [Not all functions are constructors…](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, why is Node telling me it's not a constructor?

Because it's not a constructor. :-) Arrow functions are never constructors, they close over `this` and have no `prototype` property, and so cannot be used as constructors (which need to have a specific `this` set when they're called via `new`, and need to have a `prototype` property so it can be used to set the [[Prototype]] of the object created via `new`).

Either 1. Make it a `function` function, or 2. Make it a `class`.

Here's the one line change for #1:

```
exports.Config = function(file) {
```