# Cannot understand some syntax behind JQuery extension object declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a `jquery.query-object.js` extension which is implemented this way:

```
new function(settings) { 
  var $separator = settings.separator;
  ...

  jQuery.query = new function() {
   ...
  }
}
```

`.$query` object provides you some services, but magic behind passing settings object makes me perplexed. I got to write something like this next to `jquery.query-object.js` file reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.query = { separator: '|' };
</script>
```

I can not marry this two parts in my brain. Who can explain me please on how javascript/JQuery managed to handle above-mentioned syntax to run `new function(settings)` ? What confuses me is that code like `var $separator = settings.separator;` declared out of jQuery.query scope.

Comment: `What confuses me is ...` that just makes it not globally available. not quite sure what's confusing about that specifically.

Comment: [`new function` is an antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572). I wouldn't expect the rest of the code to be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you mean [this file](https://github.com/alrusdi/jquery-plugin-query-object/blob/master/jquery.query-object.js), there `new function` is just an abuse of the `new` keyword to create an [IIFE with a local scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572) - similar to how the [exclamation mark can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3755606/1048572). This abuse is even worse when doing `jQuery.query = new function() { … }`, where the IIFE [actually returns](https://github.com/alrusdi/jquery-plugin-query-object/blob/master/jquery.query-object.js#L225) a `new queryObject(location.search, location.hash);` as in the revealing module pattern.

> What confuses me is that code like var `$separator = settings.separator;` declared out of `jQuery.query` scope

Notice that the `jQuery.query` *object* doesn't have a scope, but the module IIFE that yielded it has. Every function defined within there has access to the [local variables of that inner scope](https://github.com/alrusdi/jquery-plugin-query-object/blob/master/jquery.query-object.js#L21-77), but also can access the (local) [variables of the parent scope](https://github.com/alrusdi/jquery-plugin-query-object/blob/master/jquery.query-object.js#L13-18). Of course, that additional inner scope is totally useless.