# Closure Compiler Ignores Object Mutation

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-closure-compiler

I put the following code into closure compiler on advanced mode:

```
var obj = (function() {
  /** @constructor */
  function H(a) {
    this.a = a
  }
  var h = new H(1);
  h.b=1
  return h
})();
```

The result I get back is:

```
(function() {
  var a = new function() {
  }(1);
  a.a = 1;
  return a;
})();
```

Why is it ignoring the change I make to the object `h.b=1` ?

Comment: Try adding `this.b = null` in the constructor. Perhaps it's optimized in a way to ignore code that would result in multiple hidden classes?

Comment: @plalx I was hoping to see it add `this.b=1` to the constructor.

Comment: While the question by itself is valid, notice that [this pattern shouldn't be used](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advanced compilation options enable [aggressive property removal](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/UnderstandingPropertyRemoval), which includes some assumptions:

> It makes a strong assumption that properties defined on a "prototype" or "this" will not be iterated over and thus is a candidate for removal.
>
>
> `/** @constructor */
> function cls() {
>    this.x = 1; // removal candidate due to "this" assumption;
> }`

So what you're seeing is actually `this.a = a` being removed, and then the property `b` is being renamed to `a`.