# What EXACTLY is new doing?

Tags: javascript, prototype, proto

This is going to be a tricky question. 
Having a constructor:

```
var Constructor = new function(){
this.a = 'a';
this.b = 'b';
}
```

we can create an object:

```
var obj = new Constructor();
```

**this** in Constructor refers to window but when calling new Constructor() some magic is being done: now **this** is finding out the scope of a function it is in (how exactly is it working?) and assigning only that scope to obj returns it.
So basically it is doing something like:

```
var Constructor = new function(){
var this = {some object having variables needed for every object (like __proto__)}    
this.a = 'a';
this.b = 'b';
return this;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how it is this mechanism of creation of new object in JS is working in low level? What exactly is being done underneath when calling **new**?

Comment: and what's the point of `new function()`?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: [It's a mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406552/is-it-right-to-think-of-a-javascript-function-expression-that-uses-the-new-key)

Comment: *"now `this` is finding out the scope of a function it is in"* You seem to be confusing scope and `this`. They actually don't have anything to do with each other (other than that in each environment (scope), there is a binding `this`).

Comment: Also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1):

"new SomeFunction()" is creating a new object, and calling SomeFunction with that object as "this".

Consider this:

```
function SomeFunction() {
    this.hello = "Hello, world";
}
var myObj = new SomeFunction();
myObj.hello; // "Hello, world"

var myObj2 = {};
SomeFunction.call(myObj2);
myObj2.hello; // "Hello, world"
```