# How come process.__proto__ !== process.constructor.prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I opened up `node` repl and typed in

```
process.__proto__ === process.constructor.prototype
```

and I was surprised that the answer is

```
false
```

this perplexes me quite a bit. Isn't that `o.__proto__` was defined to be its constructors prototype?

Comment: The `constructor` property can be set to any value, so this equality is really only guaranteed if you control the code.

Comment: @Felix Kling: But if that's the case, I believe in V8 engine you will see the output of `Object.keys(process)` to have `"constructor"`, however that's not the case.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from creating a non-enumerable property. However, I didn't necessarily mean that it was changed *explicitly*. Here is another example: `function Parent() {}; function Child(); Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype); var child = new Child();`. Here the condition would also be `false` because `child.constructor` points to `Parent`, not `Child`.

Comment: Whether that boolean comparison would be true or not depends entirely upon how the object was created and whether it was purposely set to have a constructor property that will make your test `true`.  For custom objects, the language does not make that statement true for you automatically, specific code must do the right thing to make that `true`.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Because it has been tampered with.

How [`process`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html) is constructed is not immediately clear from the source code as it is a host object, but let's trace it down:

1. When an `Environment` is created, it [creates a `process` object](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/node.cc#L3574-L3577). This C++ code creates a V8::Object equivalent to the JS

   ```
   var process = new function process() { };
   ```

   <sub>Yes, we [should not do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406585/1048572). But anyway, this is how it was done, and this function is what you get when you log `process.constructor`: the `function process() { [native code] }`. Oh, and `Object.getPrototypeOf(new process.constructor) == process.constructor.prototype` holds as expected.</sub>

   Then, it [places the object in the environment](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/node.cc#L3578) and `SetupProcessObject` [is called](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/node.cc#L3580) on the environment, which [sets up all the methods and properties](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/node.cc#L2589) on the process object that you know from the docs.
2. When Node [loads the environment](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/node.cc#L2839), it will [read and eval](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/node.cc#L2856-L2857) the `node.js` file to get the function that is defined in it. Then it will [take the environment's process object and call the obtained function with it as an argument](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/node.cc#L2894-L2895).
3. That [function defined in `node.js`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/node.js#L27) now does lots of bootstrapping, such as setting the global `global` variable to the global object. It also [calls](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/node.js#L811) the [`startup` function](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/node.js#L30), which is defined as follows:

   ```
   var EventEmitter = NativeModule.require('events').EventEmitter;
   process.__proto__ = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype, {
       constructor: {
           value: process.constructor
       }
   });
   EventEmitter.call(process);
   …
   ```

   There you have it. This snippet replaces the `__proto__` of `process` with a new prototype object that is inheriting from `EventEmitter.prototype`, but retains the original value of the `constructor` property. `process` does no more inherit from `process.constructor.prototype`, which points to the "old" prototype object.

   I can't explain why they do this :-) Maybe a better approach would have been to simply do

   ```
   process.__proto__.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;
   ```