# How should I think of property definitions in object literals?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let o = {
  x: 1,
  foo() {
    setTimeout(()=> 
      console.log(this.x),
    100);
  }
}
o.foo();
```

This prints out 1 after 100ms.

Is this because it is equivalent to the following, meaning that the lexical `this` binding of arrow functions works?

```
let o = new (function Object() {
          this.x = 1;
          this.foo = ()=> console.log(this.x);
        });
o.foo();
```

Comment: No, this does *not* print out `1` after 100ms. It does so only when you call `o.foo()` somewhere!

Comment: [Never use `new function(){}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406552/is-it-right-to-think-of-a-javascript-function-expression-that-uses-the-new-key-as-static) btw

Comment: @Bergi - you are distinguishing between the question and your comment by the absence of parens?

Comment: no, the parenthesis and the naming don't matter. It's the `new`+function expression antipattern that should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because it is equivalent to the following, meaning that the lexical this binding of arrow functions works?

No, it's much simpler than that. It's equivalent to

```
var o = {
  x: 1,
  foo: function() {
    setTimeout(()=> 
      console.log(this.x),
    100);
  }
};
o.foo();
```

and with the arrow function converted:

```
var o = {
  x: 1,
  foo: function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(self.x)
    }, 100);
  }
};
o.foo();
```

Since you are calling `o.foo()`, `this` inside `foo` refers to `o`. Because an arrow function's `this` is subject to lexical scope, it access `foo`'s `this`.