# Arrow functions - why does this print the global object to the console?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why does `o.foo()` print the global object to the console?

```
let o = {
  foo: () => console.log(this),
  bar() { console.log(this); }
};

o.foo(); // Global object / undefined
o.bar(); // o
```

I thought the equivalent of the arrow function might be something like this (but it's not):

```
let o = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log(this);
    },
    bar() {   
        console.log(this);
    }
};

o.foo(); // o
o.bar(); // o
```

Comment: I assume you derived the equivalence from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29945519/218196). Note the big difference: I declared `self` *outside* the arrow function, you are declaring it *inside* the arrow function. that's not how it works. The equivalent would be `var self = this; let o = {foo: console.log(self); };`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes. I thanks for clarifying that. That was my misunderstanding (which I realised after writing the question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrow functions *retain* the `this` of the *surrounding [execution context](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-execution-contexts)* from when they were declared. They don't change `this` all the time, like normal methods do.

In your example, there is no execution context surrounding `foo`, so `this` is `undefined`. This is the same behavior as a function declared using the `function` keyword at the same scope and called in the same way. You can test that with:

```
let foo = () => { return this; }
console.log(foo() === undefined);
```

From [the spec at 14.2.16](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> Any reference to arguments, super, or this within an ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment. Typically this will be **the Function Environment of an immediately enclosing function**.

(emphasis mine)

Interestingly, when that arrow function is present in the global scope, [the BabelJS transpiler](https://babeljs.io/) simply outputs

```
"use strict";

var foo = function foo() {
  return undefined;
};
```

as if that were the only correct behavior. Reading the spec, it doesn't seem quite as strict, but this does seem like the right thing to do.

It appears that you can end up with the global object as this if you manage to run ES6 code using arrows without modules. Per [the spec at 10.2.1](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-strict-mode-code):

> - Global code is strict mode code if it begins with a Directive Prologue that contains a Use Strict Directive (see 14.1.1).
> - Module code is always strict mode code.

So it is *possible* to get ES6 code in a non-strict context. If that happens, then `this` will use the classical fallback and be set to `window` (in [the spec at 9.2](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects) as an undefined `[[ThisMode]]`).

In this example, there is no immediately enclosing function, thus no lexical scope to pick up, so `this` ends up undefined.

In your second example, the capture on `this` doesn't make a difference:

```
let o = {
    foo: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log(self);
    },
    bar() {         
        console.log(this);
    }
};
```

The `var self` statement is within the function, so it won't do anything. If you were to do:

```
let o = {
    foo: function() {
        var self = this;
        return function() {
            console.log(self);
        }
    }(),
    bar() {         
        console.log(this);
    }
};
```

then it will have the behavior you expect (roughly), although `this` will still be undefined (or the global object) because you're not within a lexical environment to be captured.

If you were to use

```
class Foo {
  bar() {
    let baz = () => { return this; }
  }
}
```

then `bar` could be transpiled down to

```
function bar() {
  var _this = this;

  var baz = function baz() {
    return _this;
  };
}
```

which does what you *want*. That only works because there is a surrounding context to be captured.

Comment: "In this example, there is no immediately enclosing function, thus no lexical scope to pick up, so this ends up undefined." ...or the global object in sloppy mode?

Comment: I do not think "function scope" is a well-defined term in the spec. You mean `[[Environment]]` internal property?

Comment: I can't actually reproduce the second behavior on my machine, but that's probably because Babel simply transpiles `let foo = () => { return this; }` straight to `var foo = function foo() { return undefined; };` (no joke). That makes me think that this is a sufficiently-well-defined behavior to rely on.

Comment: Replaced "function scope" with the correct terminology and added some info about the second example.

Comment: "In your example, there is no execution context surrounding foo" I know what you mean, but the global execution context surrounds it (if run in the global scope).

Comment: @BenAston I don't think "lexical environment"/"execution context" allows that, actually. It clearly lists the context as being null if the function is at the script-level (i.e., just part of a script body, not on a prototype). "If the context is evaluating the code of a Script or Module, the value is null."

Comment: No, there is a global execution context. What you might be referring to is the `null` `[[Outer]]` property on the `[[LexicalEnvironment]]` of the global execution context? Happy to be corrected.

Comment: @BenAston yknow, I'm honestly not sure. I don't see anything helpfully clear in the spec and nobody in [the JS SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) has volunteered an answer yet.

Comment: OK, there are a couple of issues with my earlier comment, but the thrust remains correct I believe. Step 3 of http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation is the creation of said context. It is not called the global execution context in the spec though.

Comment: FWIW, bable converts `this` to `undefined` because it assumes that every file is a *module*. Modules are always strict, and their  `this` value  is always `undefined`. `this` will refer to `window` if the arrow function is declared at the top level of a *script*.