# JavaScript initialize an object using complex reference

Tags: javascript, object

```
var ok = {
  makeScreens: function () {
    this.screens = {
      x: 2,
      y: this.x * 10;
    };
  }
}
```

I want to initialize the *this.screens* variable, but I can't refer to **x** when I'm initializing **y** . Can someone tell me, how to refer to the *this.screens.x*?
Thank you very much.

Comment: *this.screens* isn't a variable. *this* is a parameter of an execution context that, in non–strict mode, always references an object. So *this.screens* is a reference to an object property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You'll have to do it in two steps:

```
var ok = {
  makeScreens: function () {
    this.screens = {
      x: 2
    };

    this.screens.y = this.screens.x * 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: Or `var x = 2; this.screens = {x:x, y:x*10};`. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Another thing you could do is use a constructor:

```
var ok = {
  makeScreens: function() {
    this.screens = new (function(){
      this.x = 2;
      this.y = this.x * 10;
    })();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try that? *x* is undefined, and the IIFE returns *undefined* so *new* is going to fail too.

Comment: my bad.  you're right I didn't try it. fixed the x although I'm a little surprised x was undefined.  Had to google IIFE.  Does this count as an IIFE?  The invocation occurs outside of the anonymous function parens, upon `new` i would think.

Comment: [Please don't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10406585/1048572)

Comment: The immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) will be called without setting *this*, so it will default to the global object. So *this.x* is essentially *window.x* in a browser. Not my down vote by the way.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for that.  I didn't know that was the case.

Comment: @RobG I am probably doing something wrong but I'm not seeing that behavior when I console.log(this)  inside the invoked function.