# Unusual object creation

Tags: javascript

```
var f = new function() {
   this.prop = '...';
};

console.dir(f); // Object
```

How it works? First is to determine the function and then call. But in this example, there is a call then determining. How it?

Comment: it's an anon constructor. calling `new` on a constructor function yields an object.

Comment: After understanding how it works, make sure [to avoid this pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572).

Comment: @dandavis, I know it's constructor. I am interested in how it works? Call to function definition? Usually it is the definition of a constructor function and then call with the new.

Comment: @Bergi, friend, do you speak russian?

Comment: when you write "new Obj", "Obj" is the same stuff as the constructor function literal itself. therefore, you can interchangeably use a function literal in place of a function name in JS.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov: No, with that I cannot help.

Comment: How in the world JavaScript called this pattern?