# How Do I Test nested ES6 Generators using Mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ecmascript-6, generator, koa

I'm trying to use `co-mocha` to test some nested generators functionality in my `koa` app.  The class works just fine at runtime, but when I attempt to test the functionality, I cannot get the nested generator to run in my test.

**Class being tested:**

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'

class FooService {
  _doAsync(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          foo: 'FOO'
        })
      }, 500)
    })
  }

  create(){
    console.log('This never gets logged')
    let self = this
    return function*(){
      console.log(`This doesn't either`)
      return yield self._doAsync()
    }
  }
}
export default new FooService()
```

**Test File**

```
import fooService '../services/foo-service'
import Chai from 'chai'
let expect = Chai.expect

describe('Testing generators', () => {
  it('Should just work', function *(){
    console.log('This log never happens')
    let result = yield fooService.create()
    expect(result).to.equal({foo: 'FOO'})
  })
})
```

I'm running mocha w/ `--require co-mocha` and Node 4.2.6

While the tests complete w/o errors, NONE of the console above ever get logged and so I'm quite sure the actual test generator is never running at all.

If I try using the npm package, `mocha-generators` instead, while I get the log from inside the test generator, the underlying generator returned from the `create()` method on the service never fires...

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: You probably want to `yield* fooService.create()()`

Comment: Never export class instances! Either export the class, or don't use `class` syntax and create an object literal instead.

Comment: @Bergi how would changing that line change anything (in the case of `co-mocha`) when the generator that line is sitting in, never appears to run in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi Your line modification worked with the `mocha-generators` library!  Thank you!  Please add it as an answer?

On a side note, why the assertion that we should "never" export a class instance?  I was under the impression that, in the case of singletons, this pattern works quite well due to `require`'s build-in caching?

Comment: @RavenHursT The primary issue is that if you are exporting a class singleton, you might as well just export an object. You gain nothing by using class syntax. You could just as easily `export default function create(){}` or if you do have multiple functions, `export function create(){}`.

Comment: @RavenHursT: And worse, not only do you gain nothing, but you also create a useless prototype chain and leak the class constructor of the would-be singleton. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `mocha-generators`, the `it` callback returns a generator that will not be run by anyone. You'd need to wrap it in `co` manually so that mocha would receive a promise.

With `mocha-generators`, your generator is executed but yields a generator function. That's not expected, you are supposed to yield promises. You need to call the generator function that the `create()` call returns yourself, and then you shouldn't `yield` a generator itself but rather delegate to it via [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*):

```
let result = yield* fooService.create()();
```