# Testing a Yield with Jasmine that uses Mongo / Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, jasmine, ecmascript-6

First here's the db.js

```
// Load Mongoose interface
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Get config file for SQL connection
var connection = mongoose.connect('localhost/test');

// Return connection
module.exports = connection;
```

Here's the Todo Model, todo.js

```
// Get mongoose object
var db = require('../lib/db');

// Prepare schema
var schema = new db.Schema(
{
    name:           String,
    description:    String
} );

// Return model with schema linked to collection
module.exports = db.model( 'tests', schema );
```

And here's the route 'update.js' that executes the query against the model

```
// Require todo model
var Todo = require('../models/todo');

module.exports = function *() {
  // Get request body
  var input = this.request.body;

  // Update todo item with given input ID
  yield Todo.update( {_id: input.id}, {
    name: input.name,
    description: input.description,
    created_on: new Date(input.created_on),
    updated_on: new Date()});

  // Redirect to index
  this.redirect('/');
};
```

The middle ware is koa.js btw. the route being

```
 app.use(route.post('/todo/update', require('./routes/update')));
```

Question: How do I write a test against 'update.js' that has *() and the yield statement ? What would the Jasmine fake/spy be ?

Any other testing framework will be considered not just Jasmine

Comment: Have you tried using jasmines async testing features? https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: NO, but I've just come across this https://github.com/hyzhak/jasmine-es6-generator

Comment: That package is 4 lines of code which wraps async tests. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyzhak/jasmine-es6-generator/master/index.js

Comment: yes, just been looking at it

Comment: this is close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280756/how-do-i-test-nested-es6-generators-using-mocha