# new function(){} vs new Function();

Tags: javascript

I picked up some code and I am just getting to understand the `new Function();`. Going through jslint the `new Function();` was highlighted as unexpected. I started to experiment with it doing the following.

```
var func = new Function();
func.property = "some property";
return func;
```

A replacement.

```
var func = new function(){
this.property = "some property";
}
return func;
```

Both work and the second one is neglected by js-lint.

Am I doing anything spectacular here, or is this exactly the same? Is it syntactical correct to use `new Function();` like this?

Original code excerpt is attached.

```js
 var $ = (function() {

   function doCSS(prop, val) {
     var isSet = Boolean(val),
       action = CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.setProperty,
       args = arguments;
     if (isSet) {
       this.each(function(node, i) {
         action.apply(node.style, args);
       });
       return this;
     } else if (typeof(prop) === 'object') {
       this.each(function(node, i) {
         Object.keys(prop).forEach(function(property) {
           node.style[property] = prop[property];
         });
       });
       return this;
     } else {
       return this.nodes[0].style[prop];
     }
   }



   // chaining of methods
   return (function(selector, context) {
     var q = new Function();
     q.selector = selector;
     q.context = context || document;
     q.nodeList = q.context.querySelectorAll(selector);
     q.each = function(action) {
       [].forEach.call(q.nodeList, function(item, i) {
         action(item, i);
       });
       return this;
     };
     q.click = function(action) {
       [].forEach.call(q.nodeList, function(item, i) {
         item.addEventListener("click", action, false);
       });
       return this;
     };
     q.toString = function() {
       return q.selector;
     };
     q.css = function(prop, val) {
       return doCSS.call(this, prop, val);
     };


     return q;


   });
 })
```

Is any of these two wrong in syntax?

**EDIT**
After getting some of the great advice I adapted the code to the following:

```js
var $ = (function($) {

  function doCSS(prop, val) {
    var isSet = Boolean(val),
      action = CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.setProperty,
      args = arguments;
    if (isSet) {
      this.each(function(node, i) {
        action.apply(node.style, args);
      });
      return this;
    } else if (typeof(prop) === 'object') {
      this.each(function(node, i) {
        Object.keys(prop).forEach(function(property) {
          node.style[property] = prop[property];
        });
      });
      return this;
    } else {
      return this.nodes[0].style[prop];
    }
  }

  // chaining of methods
  return (function(selector, context) {
    var element = context || document;
    var q = {
      selector: selector,
      nodeList: element.querySelectorAll(selector),
      each: function(action) {
        [].forEach.call(this.nodeList, function(item, i) {
          action(item, i);
        });
        return this;
      },
      click: function(action) {
        [].forEach.call(this.nodeList, function(item, i) {
          item.addEventListener("click", action, false);
        });
        return this;
      },
      toString: function() {
        return selector;
      },
      css: function(prop, val) {
        return doCSS.call(this, prop, val);
      },

    }

    return q;

  });


})($);

$("#myElement").css({
  background: "blue",
  color: "#fff"
});
```

```html
<div id="myElement">Say Hi</div>
```

It works just fine and looks a lot cleaner. JS Lint is nice to me and I can tackle the next issue.

Comment: Why do you even use `Function` instead of an object `{}` in your code?

Comment: It is syntactically correct of course, or you'd get a syntax error when loading the file. JSLint flags it because Crockford didn't think you should create functions like that. Also, I'm with @zerkms; neither of them are doing anything that that you couldn't do with `var q = {};`.

Comment: @zerkms - What I understand is that the Function is attached to each instance when the `$(selector, context)` is called. Each object created will gain its own executable methods.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I'll give that a spin ...

Comment: they do something different. `typeof (new Function) === "function"`, `typeof (new function(){}) === "object"`.

Comment: @Daniel for the code you provided I don't see how `var q = new Function();` behaviour would be different to `var q = {};`

Comment: **Never ever** [use `new function`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572)!

Comment: only problem with `new Function` is that in order to give it any code, you'd have to pass it in as a string which makes it harder to statically analyse/optimise

Comment: There is so much wrong with both syntaxes. What are you actually trying to do? What result do you need? Is `func` supposed to be a function? If yes, what should it do when called? And yes, you really could need a [codereview.SE] on your original code (at least from what you've shown as an excerpt).

Comment: @Bergi - Since you asked, I changed the snippet. This is how it came from a YouTube source.

Comment: @Daniel Really? Wow, that is horrible code. Can you link the source, please?

Comment: Looks like someone took a stab at creating a little library, and did a poor job in doing so.

Comment: @Bergi - I do like the functionality. I like to chain methods like jQuery. This functionality will be injected into a controller. I will read that link you posted. I would love some critique ;-) ..here is the source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABSperKuIYY

Comment: @adeneo - That's correct .. It is meant for a little framework.

Comment: @Daniel Is it just me or is that a video without sound? No commentary, just typing? There are so many so much better ones to watch. Btw, you forgot the invocation of the IIFE shown in the video. Regarding the question, just use `var q = {}` and drop the functions. About the rest of the code, I rather not comment, but if you want you can ask a question at [codereview.SE].

Comment: @Bergi - Yes, it is without sound. I adapted the code and added (a working) example to the above question. I read your post on constructor leakage. That was helpful. As for the rest I adapted the code a bit. I am sure I am in for critique and am a thankful receiver. I will have a look at Code Review and take my "beating" .. ;-) .. Thanks for the help here so far.

Comment: @Bergi - You refer to better sources. Could you point out one or two that you know and carry better syntax?

Comment: @Daniel Nah, I don't know any (I don't watch such), it's just when someone links a video and I skim over it they are of better quality usually. Maybe go by view count?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the first case, you create a new object and you apply the `Function` constructor.

> Return value is a **function**.

In the second example, you create a new object and you apply an **anonymous function** as constructor.

> Return value is an **object**.

Comment: …but not an ordinary object like you'd get from evaluating `{}` or `new Object`.

Comment: Of course, because its `constructor` will point to the anonymous function passed after `new` operator, and its prototype chain will contain two prototypes, but it won't contain any other method than with an object created with `{}` or `new Object`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I started to get the constructor through the comment. I do understand the constructor, but never really placed it into its context with the `function`.

Answer (score 10):

Both statements are indeed different. I will focus on the second statement to point out the difference.

```
var newObj1 = new function () {
    this.prop1 = "test1";
    this.prop2 = "test2"
};
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
var Example = function () {
    this.prop1 = "test1";
    this.prop2 = "test2"
};

var newObj2 = new Example();
```

The only difference being that in the first example the constructor function called is an anonymous function. Note, that when a function is called with the `new` keyword in javascript it exhibits [special behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

In your first statement the constructor function called is an already defined function, [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

As has been pointed out your first statement returns a function while the second returns an object. Neither, is wrong but one returning a function and the other an object could have implications in other sections of your code.

Comment: The second function is "anonymous" too. ;-)

Comment: @RobG That's true... I guess I meant that the anonymous function was called immediately, instead of assigned and reused later on.

Comment: It seems that [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Difference_between_Function_constructor_and_function_declaration) should also be used in a different context, which is to take a string. Wouldn't the source code I posted be wrong at that?

Comment: In the context of your code using an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals), like you did in your edit, is the better approach. What `Function` allows you to do is compose a function with strings (strings for arguments and for function body) but they lack closures so they can exhibit unexpected behavior.

Comment: @RobG In the second example, the function is not anonymous as it's directly assigned to `Example`: Its `name` property equals `"Example"`.

Comment: @kube—that is an inferred name which I think stems from ECMAScript 2015. The function is unreachable from inside itself (e.g. for recursion) because it doesn't have a name. Consider `var x = (function(){return function(){}}())`. Which function is/isn't anonymous? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is not right approach to create objects
because objects created through new Function()  are less efficient than the functions created using function expression

The global Function object has no methods or properties of its own, however, since it is a function itself it does inherit some methods and properties through the prototype chain from Function.prototype

for more reference
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Hope this helps

Check the following code snippet

```js
var func = new Function();
func.property = "some property";
"some property"
console.log(func);
```

now when you check in the console it says it as anonymous
but when an object created through function expression

```js
var func=new function(){this.x=10;}
console.log(func);
```

this returns an objects
I guess you understand the difference

Comment: I don't think this at all answers the question

Comment: "objects created through new Function() are less efficient than the functions created using function expression" --- this needs some scientific evidence.

Comment: @zerkms regardless I don't think this is related to the question?

Comment: @chiliNUT well, whether it addresses the initial question or not - is another story. My point was about that very phrase in isolation.

Comment: @zerkms word. in isolation we are in agreement about that.

Comment: They are less efficient because object created through Function would return anonymous function where as with expression it returns an object

Comment: "They are less efficient because object created through Function would return anonymous function where as with expression it returns an object" --- this makes no sense, sorry.

Comment: It's less efficient because the constructor takes a string as the function body, and that string would have to be parsed into code, doing some sort of evaluation.

Comment: @Geeky—whether the function has a name or not is irrelevant, it's just a pointer to the function object. Performance tests across implementations have frequently shown that something that is more efficient in one is not in another, so broad claims about performance or efficiency must be supported by solid evidence from a broad spectrum of implementations.