# How to make a class in ecma6 within an encapsulation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ecma6 javascript, how can I make a class that is only defined in a scope of something like:

```
var name_space = new function() {

    class ball {
      ....
    }

    var handball = new ball();  // real object

};

var handball = new ball(); // error, ball not defined
```

is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you provide an example use case?

Comment: I tried it and I got an error for the last line. So isn't it already doing what you want?

Comment: It is pseudo code, i am trying to encapsulate a class definition.

Comment: I took out the `....` and ran it in the browser console, it did exactly what you wanted.

Comment: What value do you expect `name_space` to have?

Comment: [**Never** use `new function() {…}`!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10406585/1048572)

Comment: Well it will get the new function instance, but it's value is not the point of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
(() => {
  class Ball {

  }

  let handball = new Ball(); // works
})();

let handball = new Ball(); // ReferenceError
```

You *probably* don't want to do this, though. [ES6 modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) are a pleasant alternative to the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) pattern.

Comment: Are you saying that in es6, having global namespaces doesn't work if you do import?

Comment: Basically, yeah. Each module has its own scope, which doesn't pollute the global namespace. You can selectively `export` things from your modules and then pull in only the things you need with `import`. It's the same thing immediately-invoked functions were used to accomplish, just without the clunky syntax.

Comment: but if  file imports like this `import foo from A', and foo is a function that alerts 1, is it the same thing as var foo = function() {alert(1)}; instead of doing the import? So foo is not in the window variable.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, so sorry if this isn't what you're getting at but:

When you use import and export, each file is a module and each module has its own scope. So when you import `foo` from `A`, it's only available in that file and doesn't get attached to `window` or leak into any other scope. Under the hood, most module bundlers (like Browserify or Webpack) will use functions to wrap everything up and make the code work in a web browser where modules aren't currently supported.

Which is a long way to say yeah, foo is not in the window variable. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Classes already are defined only in the nearest block scope:

```
{ // a block scope
    class Ball {
        …
    }
    let handball = new Ball();  // real object
}

var handball = new Ball(); // ReferenceError, Ball not defined
```