# Call an objects setter when its children are assigned to

Tags: javascript, oop, getter-setter

Let there be an object `userSingleton` defined as such:

```
var userSingleton  = new function() {
    var _user = undefined;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'activeUser', {
        get: function() {
            console.log("Getter called, done something cool");
            return _user;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            console.log("Setter called, do something cooler");
            _user = val;
        }
    });
}
```

Now if I go to use it, `userSingleton.activeUser = {name: 'John Doe'};` works great! I get a "Setter called, do something cooler".

However, if I try to do `userSingleton.activeUser.name = 'John Doe';` I instead get a "Getter called, done something cool" and `userSingleton._user` is not updated.

What's happening is it's trying to set the `name` property of the object returned by the getter (`userSingleton.activeUser`).

How do I make it call a particular function when any (unknown at definition time) property is assigned to / modified?

Comment: Just to let you know, this is not a singleton object because you're exposing everything. You need to encapsulate and freeze that object after its first and unique initialization.

Comment: @ele no, speaking in general terms this is a Singleton. In js however, we prefer tocall that object :)

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a `Proxy` ... however i just want to warn you: this makes your code buggy + unpredictable.

Comment: @JonasW. yes, I agree.  However, that object can suffer modifications and cause that I think it's a little weird to call this approach as Singleton.

Comment: [Never ever use `new function() { … }`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572)

Comment: You will need to make `userSingleton.activeUser` return an object with a `.name` getter/setter.

Answer (score -1):

A revisited solution [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) based with a deeply nested example (NB: ECMA Script 2015):

```
var handler = {
    get: function (target, key) {
        return target[key];
    },
    set: function (target, key, value) {
        do_action(target, key, value);
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            target[key] = new Proxy(value, handler);
        } else {
            target[key] = value;
        }
    }
};

function do_action(target, key, value) {
    console.log("firing action on:", key, value)
}

function singletonUser() {
    if (!this._singleton) {
        const _user = {}
        this._singleton = {
            activeUser: new Proxy(_user, handler)
        };
    }

    return this._singleton;
}

var userSingleton = singletonUser();

userSingleton.activeUser.name = 'pippo';
userSingleton.activeUser.age = 10;

// a deeply nested example
userSingleton.activeUser.github = {};

userSingleton.activeUser.github.followers = ["gino", "pino"]
```

Comment: Why without a setter?

Comment: The setter is not needed: this pattern exploits: obj = {}; obj.name = 'value'

Comment: I have no issue with getting the object. My issue is with doing something when the object (or its children) is modified. Like for example saving it to the session storage.

Comment: I don't see how I can call a particular function when the object or one of its children is modified.

Comment: sorry, now I understand! See my update, a Proxy could fit your case?

Comment: The set function is not called when a property of the property is assigned to.

Comment: updated again with a property of property example, this was not so clear from question.