# How to assign a variable to another variable inside an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
myObj={
a: 10,
b: this.a
}
console.log('b :',myObj.b)
```

this gives value of b as `undefined`. What is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you assign the shared value to a variable outside the object, and assign that to both of them?

Comment: You cannot do that, **this** does not exists before the } ends.

Comment: Post your full code, Surely there are other ways to do what you are trying.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the simple way to get that value in a new property of that same object as JavaScript does not work like the way you are expecting,

```js
var myObj={
   a: 10
};
myObj.b = myObj.a;
console.log('b :',myObj.b)
```

Comment: the question clearly says inside an object, this is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `this` is currently the global object, which is `undefined`. You can either create a function (closure) to ensure your `this` is what you want. Or you can either create a globar `var` outside that object and assign a property of that object to it.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish though.

If you want an example, you can do for example:

```
function Person() {
   this.a = 10;
   this.b = this.a; // is this what you want? (why?)
}
```

Then, you can create a `Person` typing `var x = new Person()`.

Anyway, what happened here was, I created a javascript closure (aka function) which has its `this` attribute. Or else `this` will be `undefined`  (Unless you're on a browser, in that case it will be `window`, or, if you're on `node`, it will be the global object).

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor or another function that sets `this.b = this.a`

Answer (score -1):

try such that

```
myObj={
a: 10,
b: a
}



var myObj={ 
a: 10,
b:this.c,
c:function() {
this.b=this.a;
     return this.b;
}
```

look here  http://jsfiddle.net/36vfy4yu/

Comment: You tried that yourself before posting?

Comment: correct this answer, I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to assign a property with a reference to another property INSIDE the same object you are just creating, you can create an object from an anonymous function constructor, like so:

```
var object = new (function() {
   this.a = 3;
   this.b = this.a;
})()
```

And then you can reference like so:

```
console.log(object.a) // 3
console.log(object.b) // 3
```

Comment: [Never ever use `new function`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572)

Comment: Okay, try to instantiate the function without the new keyword and see if you can log `object.a` or `object.b`. And anyway, the question is specifically how to assign a property referencing another property of the same object that's being declared.

Comment: function SetValues() {
 var b=null;
    var myObj={ 
    a: 10,
    b:this.c,
    c:function() {
    this.b=this.a;
     //alert("a:"+myObj.a);
     alert("in function b:"+myObj.b);
     return this.b;
    }
    }
  
  alert("Out Side b:"+myObj.c());
}