# How can I access this library functions?

Tags: javascript, oop

Just started learning JS, and been having an issue with a library i'm trying to import.

The developer recommends the following:

```
<script>
    window.sodium = {
        onload: function (sodium) {
            let h = sodium.crypto_generichash(64, sodium.from_string('test'));
            console.log(sodium.to_hex(h));
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="sodium.js" async></script>
```

However, this only executes when the page loads - I can't run the functions further down the page when they are required. As such:

```
<script>
var App = new function(myLibrary){

    this.sodium = myLibrary;

    this.example = function () {
        h = this.sodium.crypto_generichash(64, this.sodium.from_string('test'));
        return this.sodium.to_hex(h);
    }

}

var create = new App(window.sodium);
</script>

/...../

<script>console.log(create.example());</script>


<script src="sodium.js" async></script>
```

How would I do this? I kept getting errors such as "sodium.crypto_generichash" is not a function. Or sodium is not defined.

Comment: `I can't run the functions further down the page when they are required.` yes thats a fact. The library is onlx available when the library loaded.

Comment: How can I achieve what I'm trying to then? without having all my variables assigned onload? E.g. I don't want to run example() until a later action.

Comment: Assign all the variables onload? Whats so wrong with that? Oh, and remove the `new` here -> `new function(myLibrary){`

Comment: @adriani that does not matter.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'crypto_generichash' of undefined

Comment: [Never use `new function() { … }`!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406585/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

This code is running before the library is loaded:

```
<script>
var App = new function(myLibrary){

this.sodium = myLibrary;

this.example = function () {
    h = this.sodium.crypto_generichash(64, 
    this.sodium.from_string('test'));
    return this.sodium.to_hex(h);
  }

}
```

Try removing the `async` and change the order of the scripts.

And run your code inside a window.onload function:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: I get "this.sodium.crypto_generichash is not a function" but within this.example if I console.log(window.sodium OR this.sodium), I can see all the functions are there?

Comment: Still getting the same "is not a function" issue, here's my current code for reference: https://jsbin.com/muxawegiji/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I think that sodium.js src url doesn't work as expected, because in the code you share on jsbin is undefined.

Comment: Yes you are right, you can find it here if you like to download it: https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js/tree/master/dist/browsers I still can't seem to call functions that are defined in the window.onload