# Why is my function returning undefined? JS

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to javascript, but I cannot seem to find the reason why this is returning "undefined"

```
mineOre(userData.pickaxe, playerData.questid);

    var newOre = new function () {
        var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        //console.log(chance);
        /*
        20% Iron
        30% Coal
        5% Diamond
        3% Emerald
        1% Brandons Hair
        41% Stone
        */
        if (chance < 20) {
            return "Iron";
        } else if (chance < 50) {
            return "Coal";
        } else if (chance < 55) {
            return "Diamond";
        } else if (chance < 58) {
            return "Emerald";
        } else if (chance < 59) {
            return "BrandonsHair";
        } else return "Stone";
    }


    function mineOre(pickaxe, questid) {
        console.log(newOre);
    }
```

Comment: Every function returns `undefined` by default if no `return` statement is provided. In your case `mineOre` definitely returns `undefined` because it doesn't return anything. And since `newOre` is a function, probably what you were trying to do there is `console.log(newOre());`

Comment: @choz however (though it's hard to tell exactly what's going on) the anonymous function is invoked with `new`, so call should set `newOre` to an empty object (the string return values would be ignored).

Comment: Ah but the call to `mineOre()` is made before `newOre` is initialized, so it's `undefined` at that point. Now it makes sense :)

Comment: @Pointy and @undefined - You guys are right. I totally didn't pay attention to that `new` keyword.

Comment: [Never ever use `new function`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406552/is-it-right-to-think-of-a-javascript-function-expression-that-uses-the-new-key-as-static) - and it doesn't even work in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making the call to `mineOre()` *before* the variable `newOre` is initialized. If you move the `mineOre()` call to after that initialization, then you'll see that `newOre` is an empty object. It's an object and not one of those strings because your code invokes that anonymous function with `new`.

If what you want is for `newOre` to be one of those strings, get rid of `new` and add parentheses after the closing `}` of the function:

```
 var newOre = function () {
    var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    //console.log(chance);
    /*
    20% Iron
    30% Coal
    5% Diamond
    3% Emerald
    1% Brandons Hair
    41% Stone
    */
    if (chance < 20) {
        return "Iron";
    } else if (chance < 50) {
        return "Coal";
    } else if (chance < 55) {
        return "Diamond";
    } else if (chance < 58) {
        return "Emerald";
    } else if (chance < 59) {
        return "BrandonsHair";
    } else return "Stone";
}();
```

Comment: Well I copied his code directly into a file to run with Node and it logged `undefined`. Moving the function call to after the declaration made it log `{}`.