# Constructor function

Tags: javascript, function, new-object

What is the difference between these two codes?

```
  let user = new function() {
      this.name = "John";
      this.isAdmin = false;
  }
```

vs

```
 let user =  {
    name: "John",
    isAdmin: false
}
```

Comment: [Never use `new function() { … }`!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406552/is-it-right-to-think-of-a-javascript-function-expression-that-uses-the-new-key-as-static)

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that the first `user`, created via `new`, has an internal prototype of a (nearly) empty object, and that empty object inherits from `Object.prototype`:

```
instance <- (empty object) <- Object.prototype
```

```js
let user = new function() {
  this.name = "John";
  this.isAdmin = false;
};

console.log(user);
```

Technically, the object isn't *entirely* empty, it has a non-enumerable `constructor` property pointing to the function

This nearly empty object is the `.prototype` property of the `function` - but since that prototype object doesn't have any properties on it, it looks empty. If you had put properties on the function's `.prototype` object, these would be visible on the intermediate object:

```js
function Foo() {
  this.name = "John";
  this.isAdmin = false;
}
Foo.prototype.prop = 'val';
let user = new Foo();

console.log(user);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(user).hasOwnProperty('prop'));
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(user) === Foo.prototype);
```

The user from an object literal, on the other hand, inherits directly from `Object.prototype`:

```
instance <- Object.prototype
```

```js
 let user =  {
    name: "John",
    isAdmin: false
}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(user) === Object.prototype);
```

Comment: Not completely empty though: `user.constructor` holds the function expression.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly both of them create a new object and the following code inside them is assigned to the object.
They then execute the code in the function body and can return the value.